# Facebook Like Box only visible in Firefox

Tags: facebook-likebox

I have a website with 2 Like Boxes on it http://www.thebasecamp.com/

One Like Box is associated with the Facebook Page with the username TheBaseCampBillings

The other is associated with the Facebook Page with the user name thebasecamphelena

On my sidebar I have inserted the code in all possible formats and lanaguages (HTML5, XFBML, and iFrame).

Each different piece of code works perfectly for the widget associated with the TheBaseCampBillings

When I add the code for the widget associated with the thebasecamphelena everything looks fine in Firefox (I am currently using Firefox 22.0 on Mac OSX 10.8.4)

The widget however does not appear in any other browsers.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks